# Ingresar datos a una pagina mediante un script de python, web scraping?

Tags: python, scraping, xls

Buen día, Estoy tratando de ingresar una lista de nombres y apellidos en 3 cajas de texto de una pagina web. La primera de Nombres, La segunda del Primer Apellido y el tercero del Segundo Apellido.

La idea es ingresa eso de forma masiva, ya que los datos se encuentran en un archivo excel.xlsx. luego crear un botón que presione el mismo boton de la pagina web, y de esa forma me imprima los datos recibidos de la pagina. Hasta el momento solo tengo la extracción de los datos de un excel mediante pandas.

Eh trabajado con web scraping pero esto no trata de extraer datos por lo menos en mas de la mitad del proyecto.

Espero me puedan ayudar muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En principio, a no ser que puedas saltarte la iteración con la página de alguna forma, por ejemplo emulando las peticiones que hace el cliente cuando se envía la información, necesitarás algo más que [requests](/questions/tagged/requests) y [beautifulsoup](/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup). La opción de facto es [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/), que te permitirá emular casi completamente las acciones de un usuario real con la página.

Un ejemplo mínimo interactuando con un campo de texto de búsqueda en PyPi:

```
from selenium import webdriver


url = "https://pypi.org"

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

text_input = driver.find_element_by_class_name("search-form__search.large-input")
text_input.send_keys("selenium")
driver.find_element_by_class_name("fa.fa-search").click()
```